# Why is my VBA code applying formula to all rows under a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to apply a formula only to rows that satisfy a condition, but it is somehow applying the formula to all rows.

I have an Excel sheet with a table in it. For column Q, I want to add a formula only if column K's value is NOT 0, and column I's value is 0. 
But instead of applying it to rows that met the condition, it is applying the formula to all rows under column Q.
I added if-statement, and it seems to be working when I run the program in debug mode, and check if the correct rows are going into the if condition.

What is weird is, if I try to put some random string into the rows for "else", it works! But I want nothing in those rows that don't satisfy the condition.

```
Dim lRow, i As Integer
lRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lRow 'Starts from i=2 because i=1 is the headers

    If Range("K" & i).Value <> 0 And Range("I" & i).Value = 0 Then
        Range("Q" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]"  'This is the formula.
    Else
        Range("Q" & i).Value = "" 'Doesn't work.
        Range("Q" & i).Value = "XXX" 'Works, but it inserts "XXX" to the cells. Ideally, I dont want anything, any formula in the cells.
    End If   
Next i
```

I expect that the rows that satisfy the condition should get the formula inserted under column Q, but I don't see why my code doesn't work.

Comment: Try: `Range("Q" & i).ClearContents`

Comment: Is that inside a `ListObject` with formula autofill turned on?

Comment: @ScottCraner Where should I add that line? I tried it in "else" and also in the first line of the loop, but it didn't work. It is still applying the formula to all rows.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the `If`  it should be the only line in the Else.  Try clearing all of column Q manually and run the code.  If you get formula where you should not then the issue is with the If.

Comment: @GSerg I don't think so. This is literally the only code I have. The only part I omitted was "Sub ApplyFormula()" and "End Sub". I also unchecked "Enable fill handle and cell drag-and-drop " from the setting. But it is still applying the formula to all rows...

Comment: @ScottCraner That's what I thought too. But what I don't understand is, if I run it in debug mode, the row that meets the condition goes into the "if" section, and the row that doesn't goes to the "else" section. Since the table has over 1000 rows, I just hit "continue" after some iteration. But suddenly it fills all rows with the formula as if all rows met the condition. I am so confused.

Comment: @jun It's not about your code. It's what Excel [may do](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-calculated-columns-in-an-excel-table-873fbac6-7110-4300-8f6f-aafa2ea11ce8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As GSerg points out in the comments this behaviour is due to Excel autofilling the formula as it is in a table.

You can insert the following into your code which will turn off the autofill:

```
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
```

Remember to set it back to True again if it is desired behaviour for you normally (or if you are sharing this macro with others).

Comment: That is exactly what I thought after reading the comments.. I even included this exact code at the beginning of this subroutine, but it is still filling all the rows :( Why is Excel so complicated...

Comment: Okay, I restarted the Excel, and it finally started working. It was definitely "Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False" that was the key. Thank you!